# Difference between Azure IoT Hub Jobs and Azure IoT Automatic Device Management

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

As the subject line suggests, I am wondering what exactly is difference between Azure IoT Hub jobs and Azure automatic device management.

I had designed a firmware update for all the devices in my IoT Hub using an IoT Hub jobs early this year and while understanding more on the Azure IoT Hub service stumbled upon the concept of Azure Automatic Device management which essentially does the same thing, from my eyes.

Is it that Azure automatic device management actually runs Iot Hub jobs underneath?

Would any of you be kind enough to help me understand if am wrong in my understanding or is there a subtle difference that I am unaware of?

Any inputs appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, post researching a little bit, I understand and this is my thinking that the Automatic Device Management internally runs Iot Hub Jobs where in it updates the desired properties of the device twins when the **devices come in scope**.

This essentially means that we can have the configuration set with the required parameters to trigger in Automatic Device Management via code or **manual creation** and the ADM would make sure to trigger the required parameters using IoT Hub Jobs(my thinking) to all the devices which match the parameters set during the creation of the Automatic Device Management configuration or even change it as and when you see it anytime post creation.

Basically, what I feel is that Azure provided a front end for creating configurations for the user without much need to make changes from the code side.

PS: Please provide inputs in case anybody has a different view to it. Thanks to @Patrick who helped provide the article.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-automatic-device-management-helps-deploying-firmware-updates-at-scale/) article, I don't think they are the same thing.  It looks like Azure automatic device management is a new concept, and even has different states